# IP to Country console command

Tags: command-line, ip

Is there a console command that takes an IP address as an input and shows its geographical information like city, country, ISP, etc.?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The command is the easy part, the difficult part is having access to a database.

For example, Ubuntu has a free database with a command line query tool ([`geoiplookup`](https://web.archive.org/web/20141126025906/http://manpages.ubuntu.com:80/manpages/lucid/man1/geoiplookup.1.html)) in the [`geoip-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geoip-bin) [Install geoip-bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ld5S.png)[.](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/geoip-bin)package. But it only shows country information, and uses a static (hence out-of-date) database. This tool can also query the [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/home) GeoIP database, if you have a subscription there.

There are various GeoIP databases that you can look up. They're generally meant to be viewed through a web browser, but you can look for a scraping script. For example, here's a [ruby script to retrieve data from the MaxMind database](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/179-Geolocation-with-MaxMind-s-GeoIP-and-the-geoip-city-RubyGem). Note that scraping may be against the database's terms of service.

Comment: just used the ubuntu **geoiplookup** and it is good enough.

Comment: CentOS# yum install GeoIP

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks but please use the official replacement for the broken bit.ly link: https://hostmar.co/software-small

Comment: @StephenRauch The apt link only works with a browser plug-in that's part of the default Ubuntu installation but rarely installed otherwise.

Comment: These are in Homebrew for Mac as well: `geoipupdate; geoiplookup ...`

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269787/homebrew-installed-geoiplookup-shows-no-output-howto-install-geoip-data

Answer (score 76):

This trick is even nicer and doesn't require any external packages:

```
curl ipinfo.io/23.66.166.151
```

Comment: In case ipinfo.io gets offline someday, ifconfig.me provides a similar service (plus a REST-like API). But ifonfo.io seems much faster.

Comment: Meh, doesn't allow hostnames...

Comment: $ host yourdomain.com | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | curl ipinfo.io/$1

Comment: ipinfo.io is free for 1000 requests/day (see their [pricing documentation](http://ipinfo.io/pricing)).

Comment: Another alternative: `curl ipinfo.io/$(dig +short yourdomain.com)`

Comment: @Matthieu I haven't hit 1000 limit but I'm planning to script it to check some IP addresses periodically during the day. Have you hit 1000 and blocked from doing more requests?

Comment: @sdkks I'm not using it in a script, only from time to time when I need it. I took the limit from their documentation.

Comment: If someone ever hits the ceiling on the ipinfo.io API (lucky you?), there is also https://freegeoip.net/ which has a mind-blowing 15,000 requests per hour limit. (Which under the hood seems to be running the geoiplookup from the other answers)

Comment: 10.000 requests/mo now for freegeoip.net

Comment: If you have 'jq' here's a fun one-liner ::  `curl -qs http://ipinfo.io/$(curl -qs http://ipinfo.io/ip) | jq -r '. | "\(.city), \(.country)"';`  Produces "Reykjavik, IS" for me.

Answer (score 10):

Or use whois

`$ whois 8.8.8.8 |grep country -i -m 1 |cut -d ':' -f 2 |xargs
US`

Answer (score 9):

Here's another great option. Instructions here: http://kbeezie.com/geoiplookup-command-line/

*For example, on Centos*:

```
$ sudo yum install GeoIP GeoIP-data
$ geoiplookup 8.8.4.4
```

Works perfectly.

And of course, you can always set this up as a cron:

```
$ /usr/bin/geoipupdate
```

Comment: [`geoipupdate`](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/) is a MaxMind tool, you need a subscription and the licence key on `/etc/GeoIP.conf`. I couldn't use the [free alternative](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/#For_Free_GeoLite2_Databases) (_Received an unexpected HTTP status code of 401_).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my little command line tool called "gip":

https://github.com/softhub-software-development/gip

```
# gip -h

usage: gip [-C] [-c] [-g] [-h] [-tT] [ip-address-or-domain ...]
gip invoked with no arguments starts the gip server
-C print country
-c print city
-g print geo coordinates only
-d print domain info if possible
-h print this help information
-t trace route omitting duplicates
-T trace route
```

In server-mode it renders a map with pin heads indicating the origin of requests.

Comment: What database does it use under the hood?

Comment: It's using https://lite.ip2location.com/ip2location-lite (DB11·LITE to be precise) but includes only a few ip ranges for testing in the repository. You need to download the .csv yourself and generate the dataset which takes about 10 minutes on a raspberry pi.