# Get my country by IP in bash

Tags: ip, internet, geolocation

I want to use the name of the country where I am now in a bash script. I can get the external IP using next command:

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

But how can I get my country name?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/ip-to-country-console-command

Comment: @bhau I prefer not to install any package for doing this.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I want to get the country for my particular public IP address. Maybe sound strange, but I exlained why.

Comment: @Radu What's wrong with installing a package?

Comment: @Jop Just a guess, but maybe the OP doesn't have root access to the system? Installing a package, particularly if it brings in library dependencies which might refer to files by full path, can require root access.

Comment: @Jop See Michael's comment.

Comment: By the way, to get the external IP (and only that) you can use `icanhazip.com` which will return you only the IP in plain text with no markup what-so-ever, perfect for shell scripts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use another IP locator than ifconfig.me that provides with that information like:

> Not available anymore as of 2015-03-09
>
> ```
> curl -s 'http://geoiplookup.net/geoapi.php?output=countrycode'
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> curl -s 'http://geoiplookup.net/geoapi.php?output=country'
> ```
>
> (see [the API](http://www.geoiplookup.net/api.php) for details)

or:

```
curl -s http://whatismycountry.com/ |
  sed -n 's|.*,\(.*\)</h3>|\1|p'
```

or:

```
curl -s http://whatismycountry.com/ |
  sed -n 's|.*> *\(.*\)</h3>|\1|p'
```

for more precision, or:

```
curl -s http://whatismycountry.com/ |
  sed -n 's/.*Coordinates \(.*\)<.*/\1/p'
```

for the coordinates.

That makes assumptions on the HTML formatting of the page. So it may stop working if they decide to change that format in the future.

Comment: This is an excellent illustration of why it's a good idea to wait a little before accepting an answer. +1 from me.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling ...I can see, but now I think that is not right for you to change the accepted answer.

Comment: @Radu It's okay - if you feel this answer is more useful, Stephane deserves the accept (though I hope I'll get or keep an/the upvote from you :)). In general, it's usually a good idea to wait at least some 12-24 hours before accepting an answer, to give multiple people a chance to answer. Accepting an answer basically says "the question has been satisfactorily answered", reducing the incentive for others to add answers.

Comment: Stéphane, doesn't work any more, but `curl --silent https://whatismycountry.com/ grep --only-matching --perl-regexp 'Your Country is \K[^<]+'` does.

Answer (score 24):

[ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io/) has nice JSON API for using from command line:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "X.X.X.X",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "Hanoi",
  "region": "Ha Noi",
  "country": "VN",
  "loc": "21.0333,105.8500",
  "org": "AS18403 The Corporation for Financing & Promoting Technology"
}
```

Comment: Elegantly getting just the country code [using `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/): `curl -s ipinfo.io/ | jq ".country"`.

Comment: Or even just ... `curl -s ipinfo/country`

Answer (score 18):

You can get somewhat close by querying the public whois database. It'll likely be somewhat difficult to "productify" to handle every possible case, but a reasonable approximation might be:

```
$ whois a.b.c.d | grep -iE ^country:
```

where `a.b.c.d` is the IP address in question.

`whois` is often installed by default, so this meets a reasonable interpretation of your "I prefer not to install any package for doing this" read as "I don't want to install *additional* software".

To print *only* the value of the `country` field and force it to upper case only (to make comparisons easier, for example), you can do something like:

```
$ whois a.b.c.d | awk -F':[ \t]+' 'tolower($1) ~ /^country$/ { print toupper($2) }'
```

Comment: `whois $(curl ifconfig.me) | grep -iE ^country: | awk '{print $2}'` gives me what I want; thanks!

Comment: @Radu You can save yourself one pipe by doing `whois $(curl ifconfig.me) | awk 'tolower($1) ~ /^country:/ { print $2 }'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `ipinfo.io` mention in the other answer, you could also use `freegeoip.net` as well, which seems to be officially using the publicly available code/database (which you can run on your own instance, if needed), and appears to have a higher limit for the number of requests -- 15k/hour, vs. 1k/day on ipinfo.io.

```
% curl -i ipinfo.io
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 17 Sep 2017 02:17:47 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 240
Vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cloud-trace-context: 86d62d74c999fc62715d7dff810ea16c/9504640995707975809;o=0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Via: 1.1 google

{
  "ip": "88.198.54.xx",
  "hostname": "static.88-198-54-xx.clients.your-server.de",
  "city": "Nuremberg",
  "region": "Bavaria",
  "country": "DE",
  "loc": "49.4478,11.0683",
  "org": "AS24940 Hetzner Online GmbH",
  "postal": "90455"
}%
% curl -i freegeoip.net/json/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 17 Sep 2017 02:17:54 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 230
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dacbae017e5ee70d57b251c89c4ba418b1505614674; expires=Mon, 17-Sep-18 02:17:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.freegeoip.net; HttpOnly
Vary: Origin
X-Database-Date: Thu, 07 Sep 2017 04:08:50 GMT
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 15000
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 14996
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 2697
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 39f89263d43c6367-FRA

{"ip":"88.198.54.xx","country_code":"DE","country_name":"Germany","region_code":"BY","region_name":"Bavaria","city":"Nuremberg","zip_code":"90455","time_zone":"Europe/Berlin","latitude":49.4478,"longitude":11.0683,"metro_code":0}
%
```

Comment: `freegeoip ` doesn't seem to be still available: `curl -i freegeoip.net/json/` returns `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`.

Comment: FYI a query to `freegeoip.net/json` permanently (HTTP 301) redirects to `freegeoip.net/shutdown`, which is a domain parking/advertising page. "Domain Parking is a simple way to earn money from your domains' natural traffic. If you have registered domain names, but they are not currently being used, then domain parking is a great way to put those domains to work, earning you revenue. " The domain itself redirects to a IP-address user data API/broker business.